# API "POST" shows successful but won't reflect changes on database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, adminlte

I have a basic web application that has been coded in php. 
The app carries out CRUD operations by making use of an API made through PHP. When I try to use my update.php API endpoint, I get a successful response but no changes reflect in db.

Project Structure
[Project_Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMEDV.png)

**update.php in api/mailbox**

```
<?php

// include database and object files
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/mailbox.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// prepare mailbox object
$mailbox = new Mailbox($db);

//For diagnostics
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
echo $data[""];


// set ID property of product to be edited
$mailbox_id->mailbox_id = $data->mailbox_id;


// set mailbox property values
$mailbox->username = $_POST['username'];
$mailbox->password = base64_encode($_POST['password']);
$mailbox->name = $_POST['name'];
$mailbox->quota = $_POST['quota'];
$mailbox->modified = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$mailbox->active = $_POST['active'];
$mailbox->mailbox_id = $_POST['mailbox_id'];

// create the mailbox
if($mailbox->update()){
    $mailbox_arr=array(
        "status" => true,
        "message" => "Successfully Updated Mailbox"
    );
}
else{
    $mailbox_arr=array(
        "status" => false,
        "message" => "Mailbox already exists!"
    );
}
print_r(json_encode($mailbox_arr));
?>
```

**mailbox.php(in objects folder)**

```
// update mailbox
    function update(){

        $query = "UPDATE
                    ". $this->table_name ."
                SET
                    username='".$this->username."', password='".$this->password."', name='".$this->name."', quota='".$this->quota."', modified='".$this->modified."', active='".$this->active."'
                WHERE
                    mailbox_id= '".$this->mailbox_id."'";

        // prepare query
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        // execute query
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**update.php (The rendered page, on clicking update, the error is: **Mailbox already exists**)**

```
<?php
  $content = '<div class="container"
              <div class="row">
                <!-- left column -->
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <!-- general form elements -->
                  <div class="box box-primary">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                      <h3 class="box-title">Update Mailbox</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <!-- form start -->
                    <form role="form">
                      <div class="box-body">
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleMBID1">Mailbox ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mailbox_id" placeholder="Mailbox ID" disabled>
                      </div>
                        <label for="exampleInputUserName1">User Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username e.g jsmith">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputName1">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name of User">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputMaildir1">Maildir</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="maildir" placeholder="Enter Maildir" disabled>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputQuota1">Quota (0=Unlimited)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quota" placeholder="Enter Quota">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="examplelocalpart1">Local Part</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="local_part" placeholder="localpart" disabled>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampledomain1">Domain</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="domain" placeholder="domain" disabled>

                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="examplecreated1">Created</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="created" placeholder="Created" disabled>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="examplemodified1">Modified</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modified" placeholder="Modified">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleactive1">Active (0=Not Active, 1=Active)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="active" placeholder="Enter 0 or 1">
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.box-body -->
                      <div class="box-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="UpdateMailbox()" value="Update"></input>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.box -->
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>';

  include('../master.php');
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../api/mailbox/read_single.php?mailbox_id=<?php echo $_GET['mailbox_id']; ?>",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#username').val(data['username']);
                $('#password').val(data['password']);
                $('#name').val(data['name']);
                $('#maildir').val(data['maildir']);
                $('#quota').val(data['quota']);
                $('#local_part').val(data['local_part']);
                $('#domain').val(data['domain']);
                $('#created').val(data['created']);
                $('#modified').val(data['modified']);
                $('#active').val(data['active']);
                $('#mailbox_id').val(data['mailbox_id']);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
        });
    });
    function UpdateMailbox(){
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '../api/mailbox/update.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                mailbox_id: <?php echo $_GET['mailbox_id']; ?>,
                username: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val(),
                name: $("#name").val(),
                maildir: $("#maildir").val(),
                quota: $("#quota").val(),
                domain: $("#domain").val(),
                modified: $("#modified").val(),
                active: $("#active").val()
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result.responseText);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result['status'] == true) {
                    alert("Successfully Updated Mailbox!");
                    window.location.href = '/MailEasy/mailbox/listAll.php';
                }
                else {
                    alert(result['message']);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

1) Why is not updating when using web UI?

2) When using postman, it shows successful, why are requests not reaching the database?

Postman --> Successful response but no changes in db.

Php webpage --> Mailbox already exists.

Thank you

Comment: Try echoing the query and run that query directly into the database.If it works in database then there is some issue with your code.

Comment: How do i do that? My initial idea was to see if the right query is being sent through to the database...